# Converting integer to double - in a tableview

Tags: java, javafx

I created a program with a column that calculate the seconds (seconden). Now i want to convert the type into a double instead of integer, because it gets me the wrong answer (for example (25-2000/160)*60 should give me 750 instead of 780 seconds in my countdown timer. How can i convert it ?

Class RuniteOre:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class RuniteOre extends Application {

    Stage window;
    TableView<Product> table;
    TextField rockInput, worldInput, aantalSpelers;
    int seconden;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        table = new TableView<>();
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Runite Ore - Calculator");

        //Rock column
        TableColumn<Product, String> rockColumn = new TableColumn<>("Rock");
        rockColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        rockColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("rock"));

        //World column
        TableColumn<Product, Integer> worldColumn = new TableColumn<>("World");
        worldColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        worldColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("world"));

        //Aantal spelers column
        TableColumn<Product, Integer> aantalSpelersColumn = new TableColumn<>("Aantal Spelers");
        aantalSpelersColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        aantalSpelersColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("aantalSpelers"));


        TableColumn<Product, Integer> secondenColumn = new TableColumn<>("Seconden");
        secondenColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().secondsProperty().asObject());

        table.getItems().addListener((Change<? extends Product> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    for (Product item : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                        int startValue = item.getSeconden() ;
                        Timeline countdown = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> 
                            item.setSeconden(item.getSeconden() - 1)
                        ));
                        countdown.setCycleCount(startValue);
                        countdown.play();
                    }
                }
            }
        }); 




        //Rock input
        rockInput = new TextField();
        rockInput.setPromptText("Rocks");
        rockInput.setMinWidth(100);

        //World input
        worldInput= new TextField();
        worldInput.setPromptText("World");

        //Aantal spelers input
        aantalSpelers = new TextField();
        aantalSpelers.setPromptText("Aantal Spelers");

        //Button
        Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction(e -> addButtonClicked());
        Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete");
        deleteButton.setOnAction(e -> deleteButtonClicked());

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        hBox.setSpacing(10);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(rockInput, worldInput, aantalSpelers, addButton, deleteButton);


        table.getColumns().addAll(rockColumn, worldColumn, aantalSpelersColumn,secondenColumn);

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(table, hBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();


    }

    //Add button clicked
    public void addButtonClicked(){
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setRock(rockInput.getText());
        product.setWorld(Integer.parseInt(worldInput.getText()));
        product.setAantalSpelers(Integer.parseInt(aantalSpelers.getText()));
        seconden=(25-((Integer.parseInt(aantalSpelers.getText()))/160))*60;
        //seconden=(Integer.parseInt(aantalSpelers.getText()));
       product.setSeconden(seconden);

        table.getItems().add(product);

        rockInput.clear();
        worldInput.clear();
        aantalSpelers.clear();
    }

    //Delete button clicked
    public void deleteButtonClicked(){
        ObservableList<Product> productSelected, allProducts;
        allProducts = table.getItems();
        productSelected = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

        productSelected.forEach(allProducts::remove);
    }




}
```

Class Product:

```
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
public class Product {

    private String rock;
    private int world;
    private int aantalSpelers;
    //private int seconden;
    private int timer;

    private final IntegerProperty seconden = new SimpleIntegerProperty() ;

    public Product(){
        this.rock = "";
        this.world = 0;
        this.aantalSpelers = 0;
    }

    public Product(String rock, int world, int aantalSpelers){
        this.rock = rock;
        this.world = world;
        this.aantalSpelers = aantalSpelers;
    }

    public String getRock() {
        return rock;
    }

    public void setRock(String rock) {
        this.rock = rock;
    }

    public int getWorld() {
        return world;
    }

    public void setWorld(int world) {
        this.world = world;
    }

    public int getAantalSpelers() {
        return aantalSpelers;
    }

    public void setAantalSpelers(int aantalSpelers) {
        this.aantalSpelers = aantalSpelers;
    }

    public final int getSeconden() {
        return secondsProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setSeconden(int seconden) {
        secondsProperty().set(seconden);
    }

   // public int getTimer() {
    //    return timer;
    //}

    //public void setTimer(int timer) {
    //    this.timer = timer;
   // }



   public Product(int seconden) {
            setSeconden(seconden);
   }

   public IntegerProperty secondsProperty() {
            return seconden ;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something. Why don't you just change the type to double?

```
 double seconden=(25-((Double.parseDouble(aantalSpelers.getText()))/160))*60;
```

Update: If you don't want to change your seconden attribute to double, then you need to cast

```
int seconden= (int)((25-((Double.parseDouble(aantalSpelers.getText()))/160))*60);
```

The key here is that your keep your data to double during the division (aantalSpelers.getText()))/160) ,  otherwise it would truncate your result. Later you could safely cast back to integer

Comment: i did but i get the fallowing error on line 121: product.setSeconden(seconden);
"incompatible types possible lossy conversion from double to int"

Comment: You either change your seconden attribute to double or you convert from Double to int

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
double seconden=(25-((Double.parseDouble(aantalSpelers.getText()))/160))*(double)60;
```

**Also**

Change the parameters of your `setSeconden(int seconden){...}` method in order to accept double data types `setSeconden(double seconden){...}`

**,**

```
`public final int getSeconden() {....}` to `public final double getSeconden() {...}`
```

**And**

`public IntegerProperty secondsProperty(){.....}` to `public DoubleProperty secondsProperty(){...}`

Comment: i still get the same error on product.setSeconden(seconden); "incompatible types possible lossy conversion from double to int"

Comment: now when i compile i get the same error but on secondsProperty().set(seconden); (from class Product)

Comment: This is because your `public final setSeconden(int seconden)` only allows parameters of only Integer type

Comment: It seems may of your methods related with `seconden` are either only accepting Integer parameters or returning Integer data types, Just change those and every thing should be fine

Comment: Just try to debug and check the lines on which the errors are occurring you may need to change some data types on those lines